# Quotes in VBA with R1C1

Tags: excel, vba, quote

I need to write in the cells from Cells(1,1) to Cells(501,1) the formula

```
=FDSC("-",$C$3,"FG_PRICE(D1)") for line 1
=FDSC("-",$C$3,"FG_PRICE(D2)") for line 2
=FDSC("-",$C$3,"FG_PRICE(D3)") for line 3
```

Now my vba code is the following one :

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1 + 500, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=FDSC(""" & "-" & """,R1C3,""" & " FG_PRICE(RC[3]) " & """)"
```

I've tested everypart of the code to determine that the last part (FG_PRICE...) is the one that is not working!
The formule that is written in Excel is :

```
=FDSC("-",$C$1,"FG_PRICE(RC[3])")
```

How can i do to have D1,D2,etc... and not RC[3]??? I've tried a few things but i can't find it!

Thank you very much for your time and your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use chr(34) to represent quotation marks when you are already working inside quotation marks. For example, change your forumula above to the following:

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1 + 500, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=FDSC(" & chr(34) & "-" & chr(34) & ",$C$1," & chr(34) & "FG_PRICE(D1)" & chr(34) & ")"
```

To put it in a loop, just do the following:

```
Sub writeFormulas()

Dim i as Integer

For i = 0 to 2
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1 + 500, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=FDSC(" & chr(34) & "-" & chr(34) & ",$C$1," & chr(34) & "FG_PRICE(D" & i+1 & ")" & chr(34) & ")"
next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that the formula written on excel (with the sub) is still : =FDSC("-";$C$1;"FG_PRICE(RC[3])") And i would like to have =FDSC("-",$C$1,"FG_PRICE(D1)")

Comment: I edited my answer so that the formula displaying in Excel will be as you specified: =FDSC("-",$C$1,"FG_PRICE(D1)").  Basically you just want to use chr(34) in place of any quotation marks (aside from the beginning and ending quotes that enclose your formula string). If you needed to, you can even change the $C$1 address (or the D1) to a variable. That's handy if you are setting formulas within a loop.

Comment: ok thank you for your answer. So I have to use a loop (I was trying to avoid it by using : .formulaR1C1).

Comment: Edited the answer to include a loop

Comment: I've found a solution with any loop if someone need it (i doubt it) :

Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1 + 500, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=FDSC(""" & "-" & """,R1C3,""" & " FG_PRICE("" & RC[3] & "") " & """)"